# Has anyone worked on an upwork.com project? Is there a risk in client sending you documents, sites, and software with malware to work on?

Tags: freelance-websites

Has anyone worked on an upwork.com project? Is there a risk in client sending you documents, sites, and software with malware to work on? I would like to do some freelancing, but I'm scared that I might infect my computer with malware.

Comment: you have that risk any day when you open and read your email. Getting files from upwork is no different.

Comment: What's the difference when you receive files via email???

Answer (score 1):

While it's not impossible it's extremely unlikely anybody would target you with virus on the site. It's expensive, manual process, slow and pointless to do it for just a small number of users. Not cost effective.

Please focus your attention on something else more productive.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on Upwork for a considerable length of time now. Here is what I have to tell you if you intend to join Upworkers.

Freelancing is an entrepreneurial undertaking, it is not entirely risk-free. The risk of malware is not peculiar to any particular platform, not least - Upwork. We encounter these every day as long as you connecting you are your pc to other hardware and software.

My advice is get your computer security up to date and functioning. You may try these products https://www.mcafee.com/consumer/en-gb/store/m0/catalog.html?PIFld=-1&rfhs=1 you get to be warned against harmful sites and documents. You can also install system security ad-ons or extentions.

Go for your goals ... shits happen in the internet world ... take precautions but if you get hit, rise up, dust yourself and continue.

Answer (score 0):

*"Has anyone ever eaten at Taco Bell and gotten food poisoning? I'm wondering what the chances are of me being poisoned if I eat there?"*

-- In short... *everything* has a risk. No one can definitely state you will be safe 100% of the time. Does Taco Bell **want** to give you food poisoning? Of course not. Can it happen, of course it can.

If you use Email for **anything** you run the *exact* same risk you are asking about.